# Elegant multdimensional loops in python

Tags: python

I wanted to calculate which whole numbers can be expressed by the square sum of three whole numbers. In my case until i,j,k all equal 4.
The (inelegant) code I used for this purpose is as follows:

```
nums = []
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        for k in range(4):
            nums.append(i*i + j*j + k*k)
```

Is there a more pythonic or more elegant solution to this problem?
Ideally for as many variables (i, j, k, ..., n) as i want to.

Comment: Can't find a dup right now, but you're looking for [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: Although an interesting observation by jdowner (in an answer below) is that `product` (and OP's code) will repeat many values. By using `combinations_with_replacement` you check every possible combination exactly once!

Comment: @python_user Yes it does answer my question. But the question in that thread is pretty cluttered. So I wouldnt take down this thread here.

Comment: it was not to "take down", if marked as a dupe people visiting your question (from google) can then navigate to that question for more info if it is marked as a dupe with enough votes from other users, any way there was no action required from your end :) it is an automated comment when a user marks your question as a dupe

Comment: Ok. Im somewhat new to stackoverflow so I wasn't sure. I marked it as a dupe.

Comment: you can still keep this question up, maybe your question will be marked as a dupe for someone else's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to do this:

```py
from itertools import product

for i, j, k in product(range(4), repeat=3):
    # do something with i, j and k
```

---

If you don't know in advance how many variables you would need, you don't have to unpack the `product` into `i`, `j` and `k`. You Can leave it as:

```py
for nums in product(range(4), repeat=3):
    # do something with nums
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this for larger values, I would suggest using `itertools`

```
import itertools

def sumsq(x):
    return sum(y * y for y in x)

max_integer = 4
num_terms = 3

num = [sumsq(x) for x in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, max_integer + 1), num_terms)]
```

Comment: While removing duplicates you also remove many valid options, like: `1, 1, 2`... You might want `combinations_with_replacement`

Comment: @Tomerikoo aah, you are correct! I will fix my answer.

Comment: Also according to the question it should just be `range(max_integer)` I guess

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in one line using list comprehension as:

```
l = [i*i + j*j + k*k for i in range(4) for j in range(4) for k in range(4)]
```

Comment: Yes I did know this solution. But it still doesn't scale well for many variables i,j,k ...